# php socket create_socket blocks

Tags: php, sockets, ipc

PHP
when I call socket_create , it blocks and nothing happens.

Here is the code .
I copied it from php.net
I use WebMatrix , IIS Windows. (not Apachy)

```
$address = '192.168.0.234';      

$port = 1000;
echo "address is : $address --- <br/><br/><br/>" ;

echo "before socket_create ... <br/> " ;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) ;
echo "after socket_create <br/> " ;

echo "before socket_bind() <br/> " ;
if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
   echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

?>
```

when I run it , it only displays:
before socket_create ...
and then nothing happens
help!

Comment: `socket_create` should not block. Can you enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `-1`, maybe it gives you a clue about what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask your HOST if the settings of the server disallow PHP to create sockets.